# JSON polymorphic deserialization java

Tags: java, json

I have a file system structure as a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "rootf",
    "type": "system",
    "path": "Parsing/rootf",
    "children": [{
        "name": "f1",
        "type": "folder",
        "path": "Parsing/rootf/f1",
        "children": [{
            "name": "subf1",
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "Parsing/rootf/f1/subf1",
            "children": [{
                "name": "text1.txt",
                "type": "file",
                "path": "Parsing/rootf/folder1/subf1/text1.txt",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "subf2",
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "Parsing/rootf/f1/subf2",
            "children": []
        }, {
            "name": "text2.txt",
            "type": "file",
            "path": "TParsing/rootf/f1/text2.txt",
            "children": ["d", "e", "f"]
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "text1.txt",
        "type": "file",
        "path": "Parsing/rootd/text1.txt",
        "children": ["aa", "bb"]
    }],
    "_id": "5ce47292d866fc2f40037a56"
}
```

As can be seen children of type `system` (denoting the root folder) and of type `folder` (denoting sub-folders of the root folder) can contain other folders and/or a file. The children of type file contains contents of the file.
I have an abstract class `Component`:

```
public abstract class Component implements IComponent{

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String path;
    public abstract <T extends IComponent> ISystem<T> getSystem();

}
```

and another abstract class `SystemAdapter`:

```
public abstract class SystemAdapter<T extends IComponent>
        implements ISystem<T> {

    private LinkedHashSet<ComponentType> components;
    protected abstract Set<ComponentType> components();
    public Set<ComponentType> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }
```

I have 3 concrete classes which extend the two abstract classes:

```
public class System extends SystemAdapter{
    public transient Set<ComponentWrapper> components;
    private List<????> children;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String path;
```

```
public class Folder extends Component{

    public List<????> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String path;
```

```
public class File extends Component{

    public List<String> children = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String path;
```

I have been struggling to map the JSON I have to these three classes. As `children` can be either of type `Folder` or `File` how can I map?
My objective is to map `system` type (i.e., the root folder) to `System.java`, `folder` type to `Folder.java` and `file` type in the JSON to `File.java`.

The second part is to be able to get the `components` of a particular system and for a particular `system` get a Set of all `components` (i.e., for a particular root folder get all its files and sub-folders).

I saw a few questions related to polymorphic deserialization of JSONs but I'm not sure how that fits here. Any guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the library you are using in Java, but if you are using `Jackson`, you could, have your abstract class `Component` getting deserialized using the `type` value in it.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Folder.class, name = "folder")
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = File.class, name = "file")
})
public abstract class Component implements IComponent{
    //...
}
```

This will basically tell Jackson to instiate a `Folder` when it reads `folder` in the `type` field, and same for the `file` field.

Comment: So how do I do the mapping from my main class? Currently I am using GSON and getting the data as `JSONObject jsonResponse = client.getData(GET_URL1);`  from the database. But I have no problem shifting to Jackson if that does the trick. Should I map using an ObjectMapper?

Comment: Yes, Jackson's object to map `String` value to an object is `ObjectMapper`. It will take care all by itself to check the annotations on the class.

`objectMapper.readValue("json", Component.class)`

Answer (score 0):

As `System` `File` `Folder` and `Component` all of the classes has the same properties

```
private String name;
private String type;
private String path;
```

You could make those field protected in `Component` so that all the `System` `File` `Folder` could inherit them. As system class has an extra id field you could add only `id` in `System` class.

So finally your classes may like into these:

```
public abstract class Component implements IComponent{

    protected String name;
    protected String type;
    protected String path;
    public abstract <T extends IComponent> ISystem<T> getSystem();
    ....
```

---

```
public class Children extends Component{
    public List<Children> children = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

---

```
public class System extends Children implements SystemAdapter{
    public transient Set<ComponentWrapper> components;
    private String id;
    ....
```

---

Comment: What else should I put in my `Children` class? Is it like combining the `File` and `Folder` class into one `Children` class?

Comment: Yes.. Cildren class has all the property which file and folder class has.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but Folder can have a List of folders and I understand  `public List<Children> children = new ArrayList<>();` this line. But in case of Files it has a `public List<String>`. How is that handled in this?

Answer (score -1):

Depends which JSON engine you are using, but with Jackson you can specify a JsonTypeInfo annotation on the parent class.

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html